# Blinking issue with jqplot when double clicking on the plot

Tags: double-click, jqplot

When double clicking a jqplot graph, it is blinking and not showing the data point. When I click outside the canvas again, it reappears. This is the example. Is there any property that I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Please show some code that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It happens even for example given in the jqplot docs. For example: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/zooming.php. I am on Mac, if that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I got you. It's a webkit thing (the engine behind Safari and Chrome).  The double-click is "selecting" the div.

Add this `-khtml-user-select: none;` to the chart div style.  As in:

```
<div id="chart1" style="-khtml-user-select: none; height:300px; width:500px;"></div>
```

Does that make it behave?